# migration from azure ADB 2C user flows to custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I already have angular frontend and .net back end an I used ADB 2C user flows, now the plan is to migrate to custom policies. My policies do not work with my current apps, but work perfectly when I create 2 new apps following this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-identity-experience-framework-applications

Can I save what I have, or have to recreate my apps? does anyone have any experience?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download the user flows (they are custom policies in the background) and use them as a basis for your new framework.